# Scala generic Monad function?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, polymorphism, monads, scalaz

In scala, how would I write a generic function for a sort of monad if I want to use `pure`(or something like that)? Like this signature in Haskell:

```
f :: Monad m => a -> m b
```

The thing is, There is not a generic `pure` or `return` that I found, so I cannot really pack up the `a` into the monad `m`.

Answer (score 2):

Scalaz has `point` (in `scalaz.syntax.applicative`) and it also has the alias `pure` (so you could replace `point` with `pure` below) :

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

1.point[Option]  // Option[Int] = Some(1)
1.point[List]    // List[Int] = List(1)
```

It is a little more difficult for a monad with multiple type parameters, in which case you need to use a type lambda or a type alias.

```
1.point[({ type λ[α] = String \/ α })#λ] // \/[String,Int] = \/-(1)

type ErrorOr[A] = String \/ A
1.point[ErrorOr]                         // ErrorOr[Int] = \/-(1)

1.point[({ type λ[α] = Reader[Int, α] })#λ]
```

You could simplify the type lambdas by using the [kind projector](https://github.com/non/kind-projector) compiler plugin :

```
1.point[String \/ ?]
1.point[Reader[Int, ?]]
```